# Makefile: reading environment variables from `.env`

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, environment-variables

I want to check if the following is the correct/acceptable way of reading environment variables from `.env` in a Makefile.

Makefile:

```
export DB_HOST=$(shell grep DB_HOST .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
export DB_PORT=$(shell grep DB_PORT .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
export DB_NAME=$(shell grep DB_NAME .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
export DB_PASSWORD=$(shell grep DB_PASSWORD .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
export DB_CONTAINER_NAME=$(shell grep DB_CONTAINER_NAME .env | cut -d '=' -f2)

.PHONY: run-mysql-database
run-mysql-database:
    @docker run --name $(DB_CONTAINER_NAME) -p $(DB_PORT):3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASSWORD) -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DB_NAME) -d mysql
```

Content of `.env`:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=13306
DB_NAME="spring-boot-todo"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_CONTAINER_NAME="spring-boot-todo-db"
```

I also tried to use another approach — introduce `init` target and call it before executing `run-mysql-database`. But this approach does not work:

```
init:
    source .env
    export DB_HOST
    export DB_PORT
    export DB_NAME
    export DB_PASSWORD
    export DB_CONTAINER_NAME
```

**Error:** `make: source: No such file or directory`

Another option is to use `source .env` before executing a command:

```
# run Spring Boot application
.PHONY: run
run: run-mysql-database
    # set environment variables from .env file and run Spring Boot application
    @echo "Running Spring Boot application..."
    @source .env && ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

This works. But sometimes, I need to access a specific environment variable (e.g., for printing) and wonder if there is a better approach.

Comment: Have you considered `include .env`? I can think of reasons not to do this, but I don't know what your final goals are.

Comment: . .env && make?  If you set MAKEFILES=.env it looks like it would happen automatically.

Comment: direnv or ondir might come handy.

Comment: You cannot use `source` because make invokes POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`) and `source` is a bash command.  You either have to use the POSIX form of this command which is `.` (as in, `. .env`) or you have to set `SHELL := /bin/bash` in your makefile to use `source`.

Comment: But that won't work anyway because make is invoking a subshell to run this command, which means those variables are set in a subshell, then the shell exits and any variable assignments are gone.  That's why it only works if you put the source into the same recipe as the command with `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Beta mentioned in his comment, you just need to write `include .env` at top of your `Makefile` and it should include the variables declared in `.env` file.

Showing a very simple and working example (Files and example taken from https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/):

Contents of your `.env` file:

```
Makefile-Test$ cat .env
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=13306
DB_NAME="spring-boot-todo"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_CONTAINER_NAME="spring-boot-todo-db"
```

And Contents of `Makefile`:

```
include .env
hellomake: hellomake.c hellofunc.c
    @echo ${DB_HOST}
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.

clean:
    @echo ${DB_NAME}
    rm -f hellomake

all: clean hellomake
```

Running `make all` should first print the contents of variable `DB_NAME` and then `DB_HOST`.

Comment: There is one problem with using this method: make doesn't parse quotes.  That means that the value of the `DB_NAME` variable will be `"spring-boot-todo"` (including the quotes) not `spring-boot-todo` (without the quotes) as probably intended.  This may or may not matter depending on how the variables are used.

Comment: This worked just fine! Thanks, Gaurav Pathak and @Beta.